# Android - Retrieve data per row when button is clicked (NEXT/PREVIOUS)

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a quiz activity that retrieves the data from mysql using a Button (NEXT/PREVIOUS). When the app starts, it views the first row. I want the NEXT Button to view the second row from my database.

Here is my json

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","question":"Numbers","answer":"1","dummy1":"2","dummy2":"3","dummy3":"4","quiz_id":"1"},{"id":"2","question":"Letters","answer":"a","dummy1":"b","dummy2":"c","dummy3":"d","quiz_id":"1"}]}
```

In my OnCreate, I initiated the fetching of data. It worked well with the first row of data.

```
private void getQuestion(){
    class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(QuizActivity.this,"Fetching Data","Wait...",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            JSON_STRING = s;
            showQuestion();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            String waws = "1";
            String s = rh.sendGetRequest(AppConfig.URL_GET_QUIZWITHSTUDENTCLASSBYSCHOOLID+waws);
            return s;
        }
    }
    GetJSON gj = new GetJSON();
    gj.execute();
}

private void showQuestion(){
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(AppConfig.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

        JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(0);
        String question = jo.getString("question");
        answer = jo.getString("answer");
        String dummy1 = jo.getString("dummy1");
        String dummy2 = jo.getString("dummy2");
        String dummy3 = jo.getString("dummy3");

        quizQuestion.setText(question);

        ArrayList<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        tmp.add(answer);
        tmp.add(dummy1);
        tmp.add(dummy2);
        tmp.add(dummy3);
        Collections.shuffle(tmp);
        optionOne.setText(tmp.get(0));
        optionTwo.setText(tmp.get(1));
        optionThree.setText(tmp.get(2));
        optionFour.setText(tmp.get(3));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have made my Next Button as

```
nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String rawAnswer = null;
            if (optionOne.isChecked()) {
                rawAnswer = optionOne.getText().toString().trim();
            } else if (optionTwo.isChecked()) {
                rawAnswer = optionTwo.getText().toString().trim();
            } else if (optionThree.isChecked()) {
                rawAnswer = optionThree.getText().toString().trim();
            } else if (optionFour.isChecked()) {
                rawAnswer = optionFour.getText().toString().trim();
            }
            if (rawAnswer.equals(answer)) {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Determining if the answer is Correct or NotCorrect is working perfectly.

I would like to know how to fetch the next row of data in the mysql database when NEXT button is clicked. As well as in PREVIOUS button. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to mantain two variables in the java class as previous and next.
By default on the start of the activity previous=1, next=2;
your get url will be something like this :

```
"http://example.com/requestpage.php?fetch_id="+next
In the requestpage.php:

$fetch_id=$_REQUEST['fetch_id'];
$sql="SELECT * from tablename where id=$fetch_id";
```

// execute the sql and the json encode the fetched data.
Hope this will solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are currently viewing a question and you need to use the previous button and next button to get the very next question and very previous question respectively.Use a global variable that keeps track of your currently fetched question id from server side so that you can use the value of that global variable next time when you click next or previous.If you click next button,write logic to fetch the question just after the current question id value.If previous button is clicked,write logic to get the just previous question before the current question id value.Also handle cases where next question or previous question is not available.This approach helps if you are retrieving one question at a time from server side.